# Deployment staging functionality in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

As I look to migrate and existing project, Is it possible to just consume deployment functionality? (without CI). Is there a yaml example for multi stage deployment without adding a repo and build step?

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you're hoping to accomplish here. "CI/CD" just means "continuous integration/continuous delivery". It's not a specific product or service, it's just a set of practices that are commonly accomplished via pipelines. The "deployment functionality" you're looking for would fall into the "CD" category.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann. Edited question